# Codeigniter langauge set but not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

My issue is very similar to [this fella's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005736/form-validation-ignores-language-when-changed-during-run-time). I have loaded the language from cookie using

```
$this->config->set_item('language',$langauge');
```

Default language is english. Now even

```
$this->lang->load('langfile','english');
```

don't work as all language lines couldn't be found. My intention is just to set default language then omit specifying language file during language loading.

The problem started after I set cookie to "german" which had incomplete language files (doubt it matters). Since then i have removed the cookie, set it to english and all that but all the lines are not been accessible in the English language itself.

Whats happening?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/multi-language-support-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Thats what I did exactly +Abdulla, thanks but it failed. I am lucky i had backup.

Comment: Typo: `$langauge` → `$language`